Gatsby performance is low, even on a blank page
I have a Gatsby site, but its performance is low on mobile, even with recommended plugins for images. Interestingly, if I empty the page and return null, it still has a 68% performance on Google page speed insights while it should be 100.
Here is a link to test it on pageSpeed Insights
https://performance-p3--kip-web.netlify.app/
Here is a link to the report
https://pagespeed.web.dev/analysis/https-performance-p3--kip-web-netlify-app/qafo9q52eg?form_factor=mobile
